# How to handle EOF error from mgo in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Rarely I see a EOF error from mgo in my logs. Searching about this issue I came across this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mgo-users/XM0rc6p-V-8) where it is suggested that it would be safe to put a `session.Refresh()` at the start of the loop to handle this issue other issues like socket error, timeout etc.

However I couldn't find if my loop should be like this where the collection (*mgo.Collection) is re-assigned after each Refresh():

```
session := // create mgo session
var collection *mgo.Collection

for{
    session.Refresh()

    collection := session.DB("dbname").C("collectionName")
    ....
}
```

OR like below where collection is assigned once outside the loop:

```
session := // create mgo session
collection := session.DB("dbname").C("collectionName")
for{
    session.Refresh()

    ....
}
```

Posting this since I am not able to simulate this issue at will

Comment: The code and description provided are too light to give an answer. I suggest you to show us more contextualized code example/description.

Comment: Sorry for that. Updated the post to improve clarity.

Comment: you can use session.copy with a defered close as it only builds a connection when neccessary and doesnt hold back for too long as in session.refresh

Comment: The query is about whether the collection (*mgo.Collection) has to be re-assigned after every session.Refresh() or it can be assigned only once outside the loop.